# MySQL Query - Multiple Values

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried finding the solution to this everywhere, but cannot.

Here is what I am trying to do:

I have a cell inside my database that has multiple entries (similar to an XML file). Here are a few of the lines below:

```
main_description=""
main_multiblogger=1
main_comment="1"
main_comment_multiple="0"
```

How would I run a query to both SELECT and UPDATE a specific value? Would I have to parse this to achieve my goal?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean you have a `VARCHAR` column with values like the ones you posted? And you want to read the values and then change them (SELECT and UPDATE)?

Comment: Yes, I am not familiar with terms, I am beginning the learning process. I am trying to branch off from just being a web designer :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you store semi-structured data* in a single column, then it difficult or impossible to use SQL expressions to select or update individual elements in your data.

You need to SELECT the whole column back into your application, parse it out, modify it in the way you want, and the UPDATE it fully into the database, overwriting the old value.

* By "semi-structured" I mean the data has structure that you understand, but SQL does not.

Comment: Do you have a link to a document that may help me in parsing this?

Comment: I have no idea what programming language you're using.  If PHP, then try http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-string.php

Comment: Yes, its PHP. Thanks for the Link, I will check into this.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what "a specific value" is.
One way could be:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name='main_comment="1"'
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE 'main_comment=%'
```

Maybe you should think about splitting the column into `key` and `value`:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE key='main_comment'
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE key='main_comment' AND value='1'
```

If one of that works for you, you could do the same with an `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: This is for a Joomla component Easyblog. I cannot modify the existing data in there, one of the specific fields I want to replace is: notification_email="email@domain.com"

Comment: Then examples #3 and #4 are out of the race. Maybe the other two could help you, even if only for selecting a number of rows you have to parse in PHP.